# Codeigniter: Can I pass an array to $ci->db->select()?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter, and trying to find the best way to pass variable parameters to `$ci->db->select()`

Sometimes I need one field back, sometimes I need 3, but I'd like one function for this. Here's my get function:

```
function db_get($table, $what, $where) {
    $this->db->where($where);
    if( $what ) {
        $this->db->select($what);
    }
    return $this->db->get($table)->row_array();
}
```

Can I call it like:

```
$table = 'table_name';
$what = array('field_1', 'field_2');
$where = array('field_3' => 'value');

$result = $ci->import_db->db_get($table, $what, $where);
```

Or do I need to implode it first? like:

```
$what = implode(",", $what);
```

Comment: It's correct to use array in select

Comment: @splash58 I wasn't sure because the docs show `$this->db->select('title, content, date');` and it doesn't look like an array.

Comment: Just look to source code of select function - `public function select($select = '*', $escape = NULL)
 {
  if (is_string($select))
  {
   $select = explode(',', $select);
  }

  // If the escape value was not set, we will base it on the global setting
  is_bool($escape) OR $escape = $this->_protect_identifiers;

  foreach ($select as $val)
  {
   $val = trim($val);
`

Comment: Brilliant! It just converts it to an array if it's a string anyway. Thanks!

Comment: you could also have just run a test and gotten your answer almost immediately ;)

Comment: I don’t have a working env to test on, but thanks anyway.

Comment: xampp is pretty easy to install... i can't imagine coding without localhost.